# .net5 => Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

I have a solution with several WebAPI projects. All projects worked as needed, nothing changed in code. But one Monday (yesterday) I turned on my computer and tried to debug one of the project, which 100% worked before. But it failed with error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot
> find the file specified

What is interesting - all WebAPIs use .net5, not .net6 (error refers to Version=6.0.0.0). No changes were made in code or project settings. Moreover, I downloaded repo from my vcs to another place, code which 100% worked before, and it also failed with the same error.

I asked my coleage to start debugging of the same WebAPI, with the latest Windows and Visual Studio updates - all worked.

I reinstalled .net5 SDK - nothing changed.

I repaired VisualStudio - nothin changed.

I even reinstalled Windows 11 (clear installation) - nothing changed.

And now I don’t know what else to do.

Comment: Do you have a `global.json` file in your project? Adding one could fix the issue.

Comment: For what it's worth, .NET 5 has been out of support for more than a year, now. It's time to upgrade.

Comment: FWIW, I have same issue since 11/20/2023.  Tests pass, but debugging throws same error.  I do not want to upgrade my projects, nor should i need to since the SDK is still installed.

Comment: @PMF, I don't have such file. How it could fix this issue?

Comment: @Dimitry It forces the compiler to use a specific .NET version for compilation. Without this file, the compiler will use the latest SDK, even if it still tries to target the version requested in the project file(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft [acknowledges](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ASPNET-Core-web-apps-targeting-NET-50/10515999#T-N10522291) that the problem exists and has provided a workaround - install the .net7 SDK (out of the blue!)